# Casting URL from MPMediaItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, casting, avaudioplayer

I am trying to make it so that when someone touches a cell in this UITableView, that a song will begin to play. Each cell has an MPMediaItem associated with it. I want to play the songs using an AVAudioPlayer. I am trying to get the url of the MPMediaItem and use it to get the song for the AVAudioPlayer.

```
var songsList: [MPMediaItem] = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items!
var player = AVPlayer()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let song = songsList[indexPath.section]
        if let url = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as! NSURL? {
            let newPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
            player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(newPlayerItem)
            player.play()
        }
        else {
            print("Failed to cast to URL")
        }


    }
```

The variable url fails to cast as NSURL and I cannot figure out why. 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

After many tests, I found the problem is you can't cast a non-optional value to an optional value. So delete `?` after `NSURL` in your origin code. May it helps.

Comment: I got an error Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: @JackFrye I missed parameter name...Updated my answer.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: should i as? String? inside the NSURL constructor?

Comment: @JackFrye as! String. Because you're sure it's String.

Comment: it fails to unwrap into string. valueForProperty(string: key) -> AnyObject? should return a NSURL if i pass it the MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL key. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys

Comment: change it to `if let url = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL`

Comment: @JackFrye If it was `NSURL`, I think I found the reason. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Leo Dabus it has to be NSURL?. impossible to cast AnyObject? to NSURL non optional

Comment: @Lumialxk it only fails to cast when i hit the first or last cells in the UITable. Other cells successfully cast. For some reason, when it hits the play() line, the music does not play. I changed player to an AVAudioPlayer with no success

Comment: I had the phone on silence. the Apple Music app will play when the phone is on silent, AVAudioPlayer will not. I do not know why, but three songs on my phone that I can play in Apple Music do not have urls